# Linux C program using shared libs written in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I am doing a project, the main program write in C, it's on a embedded Linux system. the hardware supplied by another company, there I got their libs(static libs both in c and c++ language).for later porting to other devices, I made new libs(shared libs) to link with the applications which in c language,that is:

```
 their libs(static libs,c/c++) --> my libs(shared libs,c) --> my applications(c).
```

All the c static libs works good for me, when doing with c++ libs, my libs compiled good, but 2 errors come out when linking to my applications:

> libplate.so: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)`
>   libplate.so: undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info`

here are the makefile parts for compile this shared lib.

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -mlittle-endian -I$(INC_PATH)/plate
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -mlittle-endian -I$(PLAT_PATH)/include/sfc -I$(INC_PATH)/plate
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC)) 
OBJ += $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCPP))

$(D_LIB):$(OBJ)

$(CC) -o $(D_LIB)  -lm -lpthread -lc -shared -fPCI $(OBJ) $(LIB)
$(STRIP) -s $(D_LIB)

%.o : %.c 
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

**#CC use gcc**

```
%.o :%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS)  -c $<
```

**#CXX use g++**

**I have added options for CPPFLAGS like (-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions), they don't work**

For application, since all libs compiled in c language, I made my makefile belown:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -I$(INC_PATH)/logic ->I$(INC_PATH)/plate

$(BIN):$(OBJ)

$(CC) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ) -Wl,-rpath,$(LD_RUN_PATH) $(LIBS)

%.o : %.c 

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

I have tried add some other system libs(-ldl -lc) it doesn't works.

PS: the c++ static lib works just fine when I link this lib direct to c programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile your shared library with g++. Also, you made a mistake with -fPCI. Should be -fPIC. Either that, or for some strange reason you retyped your Makefile here instead of using cut and paste.

So, the line should look like:

```
$(D_LIB):$(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $(D_LIB) -lm -lpthread -shared -fPIC $(OBJ) $(LIB)
```

Compiling with g++ links the support libraries that C++ needs as well as making sure to include important information such as type information classes and exceptions.

If their C++ library that you are linking to uses RTTI or exceptions, you will need to link those in. Giving the flags -fno-rtti or -fno-exceptions during the shared object link will only break the program.

Comment: I made change on the c program by add **-lstdc++** lib included.  thanks for the -fPCI error, it never coming out a error.                     And I am not using g++ for the lib links(only cpp files use g++)and it turns out to be OK. so your advice of flags -fno-rtti during shared object will break the program, I am not sure. thanks anyway!